# no trusted rsa public key found

Tags: vpn, ssl-certificate-errors, ikev2

I am trying to setup ikev2 with strongswan using a wildcard certificate.

The config seems to work for iOS with this certificate but doesn't work for Android, getting this error - no trusted rsa public key found '$IP'

did anyone face this issue ? if i understood correctly the public rsa key is the crt file which is the certs chain. I've added it but no luck.

Comment: Do you have the host certificate installed in /etc/ipsec.d/cacerts on the client?

Comment: it's the whole chain there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strongSwan Android app enforces that the configured server address/hostname is contained in the certificate as *subjectAltName*. If that's not the case you have to configure the server identity manually in the VPN profile, either to a subjectAltName that's actually contained in the certificate (if the server finds a config with that identity) or to the full subject DN of the server certificate (again the server has to find a config for that identity).

Generally, strongSwan doesn't support wildcard certificates (see e.g. [#794](https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/794)). For instance, if the certificate contains `*.example.com` as subjectAltName strongSwan won't  match `vpn.example.com` against that.

Comment: but how then the cert works with iOS ?

Comment: iOS has its own IKEv2 implementation and they apparently decided to match identities against wildcard certificates (they also match identities against commonNames of DNs, which strongSwan doesn't do).

Comment: i've seen a vpn provider that uses wild certs and works on android using wilcard cert

Comment: Are you sure they don't also add other FQDNs or IPs as subjectAltName extension? Or that they don't use a customized client?

Comment: no customized client, strongswan's one. what do you mean by " as subjectAltName extension" ?

Comment: What's unclear about that?

Comment: googled some more, all clear :)